# How to clear selected value from Bootstrap FormHelpers SelectBox

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-form-helper

How does one access the various options for the bootstrap `formhelpers` library?

I have tried every way of accessing them, but get an error every time.

Specifically, I'm trying to clear out the selected value in a `bfh-selectbox`

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#Select").val('');
$("#Select").selectpicker("refresh");
```

see [How to reset value of Bootstrap-select after button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41883537/how-to-reset-value-of-bootstrap-select-after-button-click)

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to clear the value of a select box since its a dropdown. Do you mean setting the dropdown to a specific option?

For your specic question: You can set and get the value of the bfh-selectbox with JQuery like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="selBox" class="bfh-selectbox" data-name="selectbox1">
   <div data-value="1">Option 1</div>
   <div data-value="2">Option 2</div>
   <div data-value="3">Option 3</div>
</div>
```

Get value:

```
var output = $("#selBox").val();
```

Set value:

```
$("#selBox").val([Replace with valid option value]);
```

BFH are great components, but their documentation is really lacking.