# How to reset value of Bootstrap-select after button click

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-select

I am using Bootstrap-select plugin (https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) for my dropdown select box. After I click a button, I want the box to refresh and the "selected" option to reset. This is the dropdown

```
<select id="dataPicker" class="selectpicker form-control">
  <option value="default" selected="selected">Default</option>
  <option value="one">One</option>
  <option value="two">Two</option>
  <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
```

And this is my attempt at it, does not work. Any ideas on how it should be?

```
$("#dataPicker option:selected").val('default');
$("#dataPicker").selectpicker("refresh");
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Without "option:selected"

```
$("#dataPicker").val('default');
$("#dataPicker").selectpicker("refresh");
```

Comment: $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh'); works to reset the picker(s) on the page (I have several and this was the best choice).

Answer (score 27):

You can write it in one single line reduces extra piece of code.

```
$("#dataPicker").val('default').selectpicker("refresh");
```

Answer (score 2):

you can easily solve this problem by adding the **autocomplete** attribute to the **select-element** and set it to **"off"**.

```
<select id="dataPicker" class="selectpicker form-control" autocomplete="off">
  <option value="default" selected="selected">Default</option>
  <option value="one">One</option>
  <option value="two">Two</option>
  <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap Select 5 uses `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('deselectAll')`

Comment: it works , thanks