# Deselect All selected options in bootstrap select picker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```js
function clearSearchForms() {
        $('#searchItemTypes').selectpicker('val', '');
        $('#searchItemTypes').selectpicker('deselectAll');
        $('#searchItemNew').selectpicker('val', '');
        $('#searchItemNew').selectpicker('deselectAll');
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
</script>
<select name="searchItemTypes[]" multiple="" id="searchItemTypes" class="selectpicker">
<option value="one">One</option>
<option value="two">Two</option>
<option value="three">Three</option>
</select>

<select name="searchItemNew[]" multiple="" id="searchItemNew" class="selectpicker">
<option value="one">One1</option>
<option value="two">Two2</option>
<option value="three">Three3</option>
</select>
<button type='button' onclick="clearSearchForms()">Clear All</button>
```

I'm using bootstrap select picker plugin Silvio

```
http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/
```

When multiple options are selected in select picker I want to deselect all of them when user click clear button. I tried multiple code sample but none of them worked.

```
<select name="itemTypes[]" multiple="" id="searchItemTypes" class="selectpicker">
<option value="biscuit">Biscuit</option>
<option value="ketchup">Ketchup</option>
<option value="toffee">Toffee</option>
</select>
```

And following is what I tried for deselecting them.

```
$("#searchItemTypes").val('default');
$("#searchItemTypes").selectpicker("refresh");
$('#searchItemTypes').selectpicker('val', '');
$('#searchItemTypes').selectpicker('deselectAll');
```

Anyone have idea about it why it's not working, I'm stuck here. Thanks!

**Update**

The question marked here as a duplicate didn't solved my issue. I guess I've went through all the questions posted here related to my question but nothing worked for me.

Here is the screenshot of select picker as most people are answering solution for simple select picker. It's different for that:

```
http://prntscr.com/fj7ibl
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset value of Bootstrap-select after button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41883537/how-to-reset-value-of-bootstrap-select-after-button-click)

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I've seen that post, but i didn't solved my problem

Comment: you need to replicate your problem in a snippet . just by 'talking' we cannot help you.

Comment: @MihaiT added code snippet, strange but it's working here.... but not in code and when i try using firebug.

Comment: are you getting any errors in the developer console ?

Comment: no, there is no error.

Comment: well then you must realise that if you cannot replicate the problem it's very hard for us to help you . try adding the jquery files before all bootstrap files ( including the select file ) ; that might do it . or check other code you have that might be interfering with the code for select

Answer (score 5):

For posterity, you need to refresh the selector after clearing the options:

```
$('.selectpicker').val('default').selectpicker('deselectAll');
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Comment: this method is not working

Answer (score 1):

Put your `<select>` element inside a `<form>` and try this:

```js
function clearSearchForms() {
  $("#searchItemTypes").val('default').selectpicker("refresh");
  $("#searchItemNew").val('default').selectpicker("refresh");
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<form id="items">
  <select name="searchItemTypes[]" multiple="" id="searchItemTypes" class="selectpicker">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
  </select>

  <select name="searchItemNew[]" multiple="" id="searchItemNew" class="selectpicker">
    <option value="one">One1</option>
    <option value="two">Two2</option>
    <option value="three">Three3</option>
  </select>
  <button type='button' onclick="clearSearchForms()">Clear All</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click', '#foo', function(){
    $('#searchItemTypes>option').removeAttr('selected');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="itemTypes[]" multiple id="searchItemTypes" class="selectpicker">
<option value="biscuit" selected>Biscuit</option>
<option value="ketchup" selected>Ketchup</option>
<option value="toffee">Toffee</option>
</select>

<button id="foo" type="button">Click me</button>
```

This will help you. I just remove attribute **selected** on the button click event. This is the more important part : `$('#searchItemTypes>option').removeAttr('selected');`

Comment: this is for simple select picker but not for bootstrap select picker.

Comment: Got it. I try this with the bootstrap select picker and it's work. `$(document).on('click', '#foo', function(){
    $('[data-id=searchItemTypes]').attr('title', '');
     $('[data-id=searchItemTypes]>span').html('');
});`

Comment: This is close, but it just removed the placeholder text not the selected options, those are still selected.

Comment: Ok. Add this code `$('#searchItemTypes>option').removeAttr('selected');` after this `$('[data-id=searchItemTypes]>span').html('');`. It will deselect selected options.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$("#searchItemTypes").selectpicker('deselectAll')
```

Comment: I've mentioned this in my question, it never worked for me.